# Eclipse: "Replace with branch, tag or version" does not work as expected

Tags: java, git, eclipse, egit

I am trying to replace a directory as it exists in current branch with a directory from another branch. Eclipse fails to delte files that where then in the original branch but not in the other branch.

Example:

```
Current branch: A
Directory: src
```

In this branch src has a file called `NoLongerRequired.java`

```
Another branch B
Directory: src
```

In this branch `src` does NOT have a file called `NoLongerRequired.java`

I am on branch `A` and want to remove `A's src` directory and replace it with `B's src` directory
So I select `src` directory and go to `Replace with Branch Tag or Commit` option in Eclipse and choose branch `B`.

However, I still see `NoLongerRequired.java` in the `src` directory.

Comment: This is the expected behavior in Git even if it is not what you expect. It is consistent with switching a branch: a newly created file that does not exist in the branch being switched to will also not be deleted. It prevents accidental deletion of files. In the _Git Staging_ view, you decide what to delete or commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the implemented action is similar to `git checkout B -- src/` : the files listed in `B` are checked out, but the files tracked in `A` and not in `B` are left untouched.

If you have git installed on your machine, with version 2.25 or higher, you can do it from the command line using [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) :

```sh
# use --staged to set B's content in the staging area :
git restore --source B --staged -- src/

# --worktree to set the content on disk :
git restore --source B --worktree -- src/
# a word of warning : if you have uncommitted changes in src/, this may delete
# files which aren't committed in git yet.

# you can combine both options in one call :
git restore --source B --staged --worktree -- src/
```

`git restore` does the deletion for you.

Comment: You'd better not bet, since Eclipse does not delegates to the command line Git (git-core), but uses EGit/JGit which is an implementation of Git in Java. The command line Git might even not be installed.

Comment: @howlger : ok, I had forgottent that point. Thanks for the clarification. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: After years of using git I still feel like I don't understand it well. In subjects that I understand well, I know that there are generally only a few underling principles in a system and then there are a large number of variations created by different combinations of the underlying principles. In case of the git, I feel like I am floating in the sea of variations and haven't grasped the underlying principles, or how git is supposed to be used. Can you recommend something to read/watch/listen/do that will  help me better understand git?
Also, thanks for the answer it worked.

Comment: @Dojo : I can't recommend enough the official git book : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/ . If you already have a good grasp of how to use it, section 10 "Git Internals" is full of detailed infomation on how it works under the hood.

Comment: google would also regularly point me to [AlBlue's blog](https://alblue.bandlem.com/Tag/git/)

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.